# Does map function store the return values in temporary variable

Tags: javascript

In first example I explicitly assign the return result to a variable and return the result,

In second example I just return the result from map function and map does not modify the iterator.

Then how it return the result since the result is array and it only prints once to the console after the execution completes. Does it creates any temporary variable in memory and how it managed?

**Example1:**

```js
var usr = {
  usrName: 'Bob',
  hobbies: ['TV', 'Radio', 'Letters'],
  getLikes: function () {
    var that = this;
    var interests = this.hobbies.map(function(item){
      return that.usrName + ' likes ' + item;
    });
    return interests;
  }
};
console.log(usr.getLikes());
```

**Example2:**

```js
var usr2 = {
  usrName: 'Bob',
  hobbies: ['TV', 'Radio', 'Letters'],
  getLikes: function () {
    var that = this;
    debugger;
    return this.hobbies.map(function(item){
      return that.usrName + ' likes ' + item;
    });
  }
};
console.log(usr2.getLikes());
```

Comment: The `map` function returns a new array, without modifying the original array

Comment: Yes, `map` creates a new array, so does `filter`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Return statements behave the same with variables as they do with other expressions.

Comment: Thanks for answers about map, i have hard time which array manipulation methods creates new array and which does not, like reduce, filter, some etc.

Answer (score 1):

For both examples, `this.hobbies` remains unchanged as `map` returns a new array without modifying the original array.

For both examples, an array is returned when you call `usr.getLikes()` as well as when you call `usr2.getLikes()`. Even though in `usr` you assigned the result of map to a variable `interests`, that variable is just referencing an array, so the two examples are equivalent and there is no intermediary variable in the second case. `console.log` can safely print arrays, which is why you get output in both cases.

The two examples below are functionally equivalent:

```js
var a = [1,2,3];

// same as console.log( [1,2,3] )
console.log(a);

// same as console.log(a)
console.log( [1,2,3] );
```

Answer (score 1):

map() function generates array from calling array without effecting original array.

And in you first example you have declared variable in that you are storing final result and returning that variable.

And in second example you are directly returning result of map function without using extra variable.

So,during all itration of map() function it stores output element in memory and after all iteration it return's output as array.

Please find more about [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0):

To quote the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) `The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.`

Answer (score 0):

As it is said, **map creates an new array, it does not store the values in temporary veritable**.

when you call map, you need to treat the response return as an array and iterate through the response's items.

So in the second method:

```
var usr2 = {
  usrName: 'Bob',
  hobbies: ['TV', 'Radio', 'Letters'],
  getLikes: function () {
    var that = this;
    debugger;
    return this.hobbies.map(function(item){
      return that.usrName + ' likes ' + item;
    });
  }
};
```

You will have to iterate through the `usr2.getLikes()` values.

if you want to see it all together do:

```
console.log(usr2.getLikes().length);
```